# Linker command - No rule to make target for 3rd party lib

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile

In my code I make reference this pugixml like this:

```
#include "pugi/pugixml.hpp"
```

When compiling I get this error:

```
  main in main-bf0b72.o
  "pugi::xml_node::children(char const*) const", referenced from:
      _main in main-bf0b72.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

From another question I was told to pugi as an additional translation unit and link them accordingly like this in my Makefile:

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -g -Wall -std=c++11
SRC = src
INCLUDES = include
TARGET = main

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(SRC)/$(TARGET).cpp pugi/pugixml.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I $(INCLUDES) -o $@ $^ 

clean:
    $(RM) $(TARGET)
```

However when I try to run my Makefile after this change I get this error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `pugi/pugixml.cpp', needed by `main'.  Stop.
```

I'm really not sure what I am meant to be doing. Should pugi have it's own Makefile to build it individually, or should I give it is't own "target" in my Makefile?

**Edit**
This is my file system:

- root/Makefile
- root/src/main.cpp
- root/include/pugi/pugixml.hpp
- root/include/pugi/pugixml.cpp
- root/include/pugi/pugiconfig.hpp

Comment: I cannot reproduce issue. Do you actually have `pugi/pugixml.cpp` on your filesystem?

Comment: @myaut I do yes, in the same directory as the .hpp

Comment: I think posting filesystem hierarchy starting from directory with `Makefile` will be helpful

Comment: @myaut Edited! Hope this helps shed some light. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Makefile you try to compile `pugi/pugixml.cpp` file, but on filesystem it located in `include/pugi/pugixml.cpp` (relatively to Makefile itself). You should:

- Create `root/pugi` directory and put `pugixml.cpp` file there

  OR
- Or replace `pugi/pugixml.cpp` with `include/pugi/pugixml.cpp` in your Makefile (but keeping source files in `include/` subdirectory is bad idea).

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. Do I need to keep the .coo in the same folder as the .hpp? I'm new to this so which approach is the most standard and recommend approach, the first way you mentioned? Is this more of a library than an include?

Comment: @JamesWillson: Source files (.cpp) in include subdirectories (.hpp) is confusing. You can do that, and it wil work, but if you show your sources to someone else, he can fail to find `pugixml.cpp` because hi didn't expected that it is located in `include/` subdirectory